# c++ vector stores all elements as last element

Tags: c++, opencv, vector

So I was trying to store the matrix data from xml file to the rawFaceData vector. when I check the cout statement in the first for loop it returns just what I want for all elements in the vector. But when it jumps out of the first for loop and goes to the second for loop, the cout gives me all the elements exactly the same as last element all the time(e.g. if the vector size is 4, then the cout gives me the last element's value 4 times!), the previous ones' values are gone. Can anyone tell me why??? Thank you!

```
vector<Mat> rawFaceData;
Mat temp;
FileStorage fsRead = FileStorage();
//output xml datas to a Mat vector for calculation
for(int readCount = 1; readCount < count; readCount++){
    ssfilename.str("");
    ssfilename<<name<<readCount<<postfix;
    filename = ssfilename.str();
    cout<<filename<<endl;
    fsRead.open(filename, FileStorage::READ);
    fsRead["ImageData"]>>temp;
    rawFaceData.push_back(temp);
    cout<<rawFaceData[readCount-1]<<endl;
}
//now raw image datas are now all in the Mat vector, there are count-1 elements in this vector.
//following is avg calculation of the training images.
for(int i = 0; i < rawFaceData.size(); i++){
    cout<<rawFaceData[i]<<"\n"<<endl;
}
```

Comment: Well the file reading is confusing, you can ignore them.

Comment: I think in your first for loop, counters are not getting updated correctly which is leading the same element gets push_back in the vector each time.

Comment: Show the definition and implementation of the `Mat` class. It sounds like it doesn't have proper value semantics.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

OpenCV `Mat` class uses shared pointer and reference counting mechanism to store data and avoid unwanted deep copies.

Everytime you read the data from `FileStorage` into `temp`, the data is updated in the same memory location and all the references to the data of `temp` now point to the new data. i.e. the old data is overwritten.

When you push the Mat into the vector, data is not copied into the element of the vector. Instead, only a reference is added to the vector and the reference counter of `temp` is incremented. So actually, all the elements of the vector contain same data.

You may want to `push_back` a deep copy of `temp` into the vector like this:

```
rawFaceData.push_back(temp.clone());
```

Answer (score 2):

```
 Mat temp;
```

is Mat a pointer? If that is the case and what you are pushing into the vector is a pointer-type, then all the values in vector will point to the same address after you exit the first for-loop and hence the behavior you are seeing.

Comment: I am new to C++, so im wondering why is temp a pointer if I didnt declare it as one? because i used    Mat temp;    instead of   Mat* temp;

Comment: @user3513507 It is not a `Mat` pointer. But `Mat` is a strange class. One solution could be to create the `Mat` inside the loop.

Comment: @juanchopanza.. `Mat` class internally stores data using shared pointer and uses reference counting. Its copy constructor and assignment operator do not perform deep copy. It has a `clone` member function to perform deep copy.

Comment: @sgar91 Yes, I know that. I think it is a poor design. Anyway, I would probably just declare the `Mat` inside the loop.