# OpenCV's Queryframe() returns only one frame

Tags: c#, opencv, emgucv

I want to import a video into my project and store it to this list :

```
List<Image<Bgr, Byte>> MyVideo = new List<Image<Bgr, Byte>>();
```

I am doing this with a timer, which captures a frame every 33 ms with

```
MyVideo.Add(_capture.QueryFrame());
```

If I display the currend catched frame with `ImageBox.Image = _capture.QueryFrame()` , everything is fine and I can see every single frame. But if I try to watch the Frames in my List, it shows only the last Frame from the video, the whole time. Like every Frame in the video was replaced by the last Frame. Any Ideas how to solve this?

Comment: Use `MyVideo.Add(_capture.QueryFrame().Clone());`

Comment: See [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22953434/1231073) related answer for OpenCV C++.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `Capture` class of EmguCV internally uses a single `Image` to store each frame to avoid excessive memory allocation. As soon as `QueryFrame` is called, the internal `Image` object is overwritten with the contents of new frame.
If we want to store the frame for later usage, we have to create a deep copy after calling `QueryFrame` like this:

`var FrameCopy = _capture.QueryFrame().Clone();`

or in your case, add the deep copy to the list:

`MyVideo.Add(_capture.QueryFrame().Clone());`

In case of visualization of video in an `ImageBox`, you can see all frames because a frame is shown before querying the next frame.

Comment: If I change it to `image_array.Add(frame.Clone());`, I get a OutOfMemoryExeption after 5 sec.

Comment: @yoko... Yes that is bound to happen eventually as you are storing complete uncompressed frames in the memory. It is not recommended to store whole video in memory at a single time.

Comment: So, what would be the best option for me? Read a frame, process it, write it into the outputfile, Dispose it and go on to the next one?

Comment: @yoko That depends on what you want to achieve. If processing on each frame is independent of other frames, then this approach is fine. Some algorithms e.g. Object Tracking, Video Stabilization etc. require processing on multiple frames. In that case, buffering is a good option in which you store a few frames at a time in memory.